# Place value in different rows

Tags: excel, vba

please assist my thought below, I would like to get the value place in different rows according to the value. I believe my code is with looping issues but I can't figure out why.

The action is very simple, row A is a set of value, `if range("A2").value + 50 <= 100 then` place the answer on `B2.value`, else place value on `C2.value` and etc.

[image]

```
Sub ttest()

Dim item, lastR, itemplus As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer
i = 2
j = 2
item = Cells(i, 1).value
lastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
itemplus = item + 50

For i = 2 To lastR
If itemplus <= 100 Then
Cells(i, j).value = itemplus
Else
Cells(i, j + 1).value = itemplus
End If
item = Cells(i, 1).value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you require VBA? This is done with a simple Excel formula too.

Comment: As JvdV says you don't need VBA for this but I think your problem is that you never update `itemplus`. Your loop is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Yes, I know this can be done with simple Excel formula, what I really looking for is the concept of writing a proper looping. This is just the sample, my project does need VBA. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SJR says, you partly work outside your loop and partly inside your loop, constantly comparing to the exact same variable.

May I suggest an alternative to work through memory instead (and avoid slower calls to your worksheet too often):

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A2:C" & lr).Value
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(x, 1) < 50 Then
            arr(x, 2) = arr(x, 1)
        Else
            arr(x, 3) = arr(x, 1)
        End If
    Next
    .Range("A2:C" & lr).Value = arr
End With

End Sub
```

As you may notice, we don't have to add 50 to each value to compare if its `<=` to a 100. That would imply that the initial value must simply be below 50.

That being said, the same is achieved swiftly through native Excel functions if you would want to avoid VBA.

Comment: Its work! This is the smart way to run the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order of assignment:

```
Sub ttest()

Dim item, lastR, itemplus As Integer
Dim i, j As Integer
i = 2
j = 2
item = Cells(i, 1).Value
lastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastR
   item = Cells(i, 1).Value
   itemplus = item + 50
   If itemplus <= 100 Then
       Cells(i, j).Value = itemplus
   Else
       Cells(i, j + 1).Value = itemplus
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, its work! I can now identify my code error with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In Rng
Sum = cell.Value + 50
If Sum <= 100 Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Sum
If Sum > 100 Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Sum
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, however it shows the compile error of variable not defined.